# Open Chrome Extension popup with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know we cannot open chrome extension popup directly from background javascript. But is there a way that the popup opens when a user presses some key combination ?

Comment: `Signs point to yes`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) api enables the user to bind hotkeys that will trigger commands such as opening the browser action.

Example : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/_archive/mv2/api/commands (Press Ctrl+Shift+F (Command+Shift+F on a Mac) to open the browser action popup, press Ctrl+Shift+Y to send an event (Command+Shift+Y on a Mac))

Comment: The example in the link provided doesn't seem to be there anymore. Can you please edit the answer to show how to modify the `manifest.json` and any related files to make the extension open when the user presses a hotkey?

Comment: @AbhijeetSingh here is updated link  : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive/api/commands

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `manifest_version` of 3 then something like below your manifest.json should look like to open the popup using a keyboard shortcut.

So what is actually happening here is the keyboard shortcut gets mapped to the `_execute_action` and this `_execute_action` invokes the `action` which is by default opening the popup.

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Search Hindi Website",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Search a Hindi website using English text",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon16.png",
            "32": "icon32.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "128": "icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "css": ["mark.css"]
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "_execute_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+Shift+P",
                "mac": "MacCtrl+Command+P"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same thing for `manifest_version` 2 will look something like below

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Search Hindi Website",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Search a Hindi website using English text",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon16.png",
            "32": "icon32.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "128": "icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "css": ["mark.css"]
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
         "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+Shift+E",
                "mac": "MacCtrl+Command+E"
            }
        },
    }
}
```